# Replacing sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to replace previous database with new database. To do that I am

1. Checking for previous user_version of database.
2. Deleting old database.
3. Copying new database from assets.
4. Changing user_version of new database.
5. Verifying new user_version which in my case is 1.

But when I restart the application user_version changed again to 0. Why it is not saving the "1" as new user_version? Or I have to change user_version of new database before compiling the app.

Here is my code.

```
MySQLiteHelper db = MySQLiteHelper.instance();
int oldversion = db.getInteger("PRAGMA user_version");
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,oldversion + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (oldversion < 1) {
                upgradeDB();// delete previous db and copy new one.
                db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version = 1");
                int oldversion = db.getInteger("PRAGMA user_version");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,oldversion + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

**Edit**

```
void upgradeDB(){
                db.renameDataBase();
                db.copyDataBase();
                db = MySQLiteHelper.instance();
                MySQLiteUpdateHelper dbOld = MySQLiteUpdateHelper.instance();
                int saved = dbOld.getInteger("select value from info where name='saved'");
                int bookmark = dbOld.getInteger("select value from info where name='bookmarks'");
                db.execSQL("UPDATE info set value = '" + saved + "' WHERE name = 'saved'");
                db.execSQL("UPDATE info set value = '" + bookmark + "' WHERE name = 'bookmarks'");
                File to = new File(db.DB_PATH, "old");
                if (to.exists()) {
                   to.delete();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the contents of the old database, then you should not even try to upgrade it. Just give your new database version a new file name, so that it can be simply copied over (use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/)), and delete the old file.

Comment: Thank you to introduce me with SQLiteAssetHelper.  But sometimes I need to get some records from old database. The strange thing for me is the automatic reversion of user_version. Can you tell me why it happen?

Comment: How to keep old data would be [a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37094656/11654). Anyway, the unchanged looks like a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: If I change user_version of new database before compiling the app and remove db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version = 1");. Would it be ok?

Comment: How should I know how the rest of your code behaves?

Comment: You cannot modify a file that is still open.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115620/discussion-between-user934820-and-cl).